# Is there a word for a person who cannot do things quickly?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to know is there is a word for a person who caanot do things quickly?

Comment: Conventionally, you could call such a person *slow*.  "Tommy is always slow getting dressed in the morning."  But "slow" nowadays also has the meaning "stupid".  Is that the reason you are asking for another word for this?

Comment: Without more detail this isn't really answerable. Is the person inherently unable to do things quickly or just feeling *sluggish* or *lethargic*? Could you, in this context, refer to them as being a *slowcoach, as usual*. Would a metaphor suit you? I recommend an example sentence as well as more context. There are tags [single-word-request] and [phrase-request] for this type of question; their tag wikis have more advice

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. an example would be: my sisiter is very slow. She can't do anything quickly. That is why she is always late for work. Is "slow" correct in this context?

Comment: Yes GEdar. That is exactly the reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be polite, you can call the person **"methodical"**.

While some dictionaries do not mention speed in definitions of the word "methodical" - stressing instead, the systematic and disciplined connotations - describing the frustratingly slow execution of a relatively easy task ("He ***methodically*** brushed his teeth as I did the pee-pee dance by the bathroom door.") is common in the lexicon. (US)